# Help needed for proof of finitely generated Abelian group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I am looking at the following proof (taken from [here](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~jim/F13YR1/Notes.pdf)):

> **Corollary 5**
>   Let $A$ be a finitely generated abelian group.
>   Then there is a finite subgroup $A_0$ of $A$ and an integer $m \geq 0$ such that $A \cong A_0 \times \mathbb{Z}^m$.
>
> *Proof.*
>   We know that $A \cong \mathbb{Z}^n/K$ for some integer $n \geq 0$ and some subgroup $K \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$, where $K$ is a free abelian group of rank $r \leq n$.
>   If $r = n$ then we know from Lemma 23 that $A$ is finite, so we can take $A_0 = A$.
>   Otherwise we know - also from Lemma 23 - that there exists a surjective homomorphism $f \colon A \to \mathbb{Z}$.
>   Composing $f$ with the surjective quotient map $\mathbb{Z}^n \to A$, we also get a surjective homomorphism $\phi \colon \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}$.
>   By the last Lemma, $A \cong \ker(f) \times \mathbb{Z}$, and similarly $\mathbb{Z}^n \cong \ker(\phi) \times \mathbb{Z}$.
>   Since we also know that $\ker(\phi) \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ is free abelian of rank $t \leq n$, it follows that $t = n - 1$.
>   Also $\ker(f) \cong \ker(\phi)/K$.
>   By induction on $n - r$, we may assume that $\ker(f) \cong A_0 \times \mathbb{Z}^{n-1-r}$ for some finite subgroup $A_0$, and hence $A \cong \ker(f) \times \mathbb{Z} \cong A_0 \times \mathbb{Z}^{n-r}$.

It says:

> By induction on $n-r$, we may assume that $\ker(f) \cong A_0×\mathbb{Z}^{n−1−r}$ for some finite subgroup $A_0$ […].

I find this assumption troubling, because, then for *any* $n-r$ we can infer:
$$
        \ker(f)
  \cong \ker(\phi)/K
  \cong \mathbb{Z}^{n-1}/\mathbb{Z}^r
  \cong \mathbb{Z}^{n-1-r}
$$
leaving
$$
        \ker(f)
  \cong A_0 \times \mathbb{Z}^{n−1−r}
  \cong \mathbb{Z}^{n-1-r},
$$
so $A_0=\{0\}$ all the time! I feel like this is not really a meaningful result so I must be overlooking something. Can you show me a case when $A_0$ is not the trivial set?

Comment: Yes, consider the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ with $A_0=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\neq 0$. It is certainly a finitely generated abelian group. Do you see your error? For "some" finite subgroup $A_0$.

Comment: A cleaner proof follows from two facts: a finitely generated torsion-free abelian group is free, and if $A$ is abelian f.g. , then it projects to a finitely generated torsion free abelian group, $A/\tau(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $K\cong \mathbb{Z}^r$ and $\ker(\phi)\cong\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$, but you cannot conclude from this that $K/\ker(\phi)\cong\mathbb{Z}^{n-1-r}$.  For instance, for $r=1$ and $n=2$ you might have $K=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\ker(\phi)=2\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$, but the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1-r}=0$.  More generally, if $A\subseteq B$ and $C\subseteq D$ with $A\cong C$ and $B\cong D$, that does not imply $B/A\cong D/C$.

(Indeed, if your reasoning were correct, you could just conclude from the beginning that $A=\mathbb{Z}^n/K\cong\mathbb{Z}^n/\mathbb{Z}^r\cong\mathbb{Z}^{n-r}$.)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. With this cleared up however, I'm uncertain about another part of the proof; namely how does $ker(f)≅ker(ϕ)/K$ come about?
Previously I thought that: $ker(f)×ℤ≅A≅ℤ^n/K≅(ker(ϕ)×ℤ)/K$
Is this correct? If yes, why are we allowed to get rid of $ℤ$ on both sides and obtain $ker(f)≅ker(ϕ)/K$?

Comment: That just comes from the definition of $f$ and $\phi$.  By definition, $f:A\to\mathbb{Z}$ and $\phi$ is the composition of $f$ with the surjection $g:\mathbb{Z}^n\to A$ with kernel $K$.  The map $g$ restricts to a surjection $h:\ker(\phi)\to \ker(f)$, since $\phi(x)=f(g(x))$ so $x\in\ker(\phi)$ iff $g(x)\in\ker(f)$.  The kernel of $h$ is just $K\cap\ker(\phi)$, so $\ker(f)\cong \ker(\phi)/(K\cap\ker(\phi))$.  But $K\subseteq\ker(\phi)$ since $\phi(x)=f(g(x))=f(0)=0$ for any $x\in K$, so $K\cap \ker(\phi)$ is just $K$.

Comment: That was very useful too, I think I got it. I still don't understand the inductive step by the end of the original proof though: $\ker(f) \cong A_0 \times \mathbb{Z}^{n-1-r}$ so $A \cong \ker(f) \times \mathbb{Z} \cong A_0 \times \mathbb{Z}^{n-r}$.
If we are using induction here, then this should work for the base case which I think is $r=n-1$ so:
$\ker(f) \cong A_0 \times \mathbb{Z}^{0}$ => $A \cong \ker(f) \times \mathbb{Z} \cong A_0 \times \mathbb{Z}^{1} \cong \mathbb{Z}^{n}/K$
Why is this true?

Comment: The base case is $r=n$, in which case you know $A$ is finite as noted at the beginning of the proof and then you don't construct $f$ at all.  So in the case $r=n-1$, you already know by induction that $\ker(f)$ is finite.